# Increased heap size not effective

Tags: node.js

I would like to increase the V8 heap size for nodejs app and I am using below command, but it does not seem to be effective.

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 start.js
```

When I check the heap statistics with `require('v8').getHeapStatistics()`, it spits out that heap size limit is around 1.5GB although I have increased it to 8GB.

```
{ total_heap_size: 73699328,
  total_heap_size_executable: 3145728,
  total_physical_size: 70562064,
  total_available_size: 1466309696,
  used_heap_size: 40996944,
  heap_size_limit: 1526909922,
  malloced_memory: 16384,
  peak_malloced_memory: 1913048,
  does_zap_garbage: 0 }
```

The error message I got is:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
>   failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Command to start app is:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 start.js
```

My node version is v10.11.0

Comment: I can't reproduce in v10.13.0: `heap_size_limit: 8769069275` (also can't reproduce in v10.9.0). Tested on macOS.

Comment: Which OS? Can't reproduce it either on Ubuntu 18.04, Node.js v10.13.0

Comment: OS : OpenSuse Leap 15

Comment: What does `node --max-old-space-size=8192  -pe "require('v8').getHeapStatistics()"` output?

Comment: That gives me the updated heap space: `{ total_heap_size: 6537216,
  total_heap_size_executable: 1048576,
  total_physical_size: 5176848,
  total_available_size: 8762865392,
  used_heap_size: 3827000,
  heap_size_limit: 8769069275,
  malloced_memory: 8192,
  peak_malloced_memory: 421528,
  does_zap_garbage: 0 }
`

Comment: At what point in `start.js` are you logging the output of `getHeapStatistics`?

Comment: @robertklep : thank you for the pointer. I was logging it in service.js. I was using the `cluster-service` in the start.js script which would inturn call my service.js. If I invoke the service.js directly importing it, the memory is updated and it is indeed effective.

Comment: did you fixed this issue?